# randomizing & sending attachments in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command that sends a random picture from the input directory once an `on_message` is triggered. the problem is that instead of sending a random attachment, it just sends a random name of a file. i thought it was maybe because of the `message.channel.send`, but i couldn't find any solution. I'm just looking for how i can get it to send a random attachment instead of the name of it

thanks in advance. 
my code:

```
   if message.content == "!peek":
       await message.channel.send(random.choice(os.listdir(r"C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\discord bot\attachments")))
```

Answer (score 0):

As [specified here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-upload-an-image), you have to use a `File` object.

You could do something like that :

```python
import os, random
from discord import File

...

@command()
async def img(self, ctx):

    dir = "C:\\Users\\...\\image_folder"
    file_name = random.choice(os.listdir(dir))

    with open(f'{dir}\\{file_name}', 'rb') as f:
        await ctx.send(file=File(f, 'new_filename.png'))
```